# "from random import randint" throwing "ImportError: bad magic number in 'random': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, runtime-error, importerror

I have a python script that does incorrect math.
here it is:

```
from random import randint
while 1==1:
    try:
        exp = input()
        if exp=="1+1":
            print("=3")
        else :
            answer = exp
            while answer == exp:
                answer = randint(0, exp+10)
            print(answer)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print(259)
```

when i run it, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/the_name_of_my_home_folder/Documents/the name of the file.py", line 1, in <module>
    from random import randint
ImportError: bad magic number in 'random': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'
```

I am using python 3.5.1 on a mac.

Comment: @LexScarisbrick I don't think it is.

Comment: Have your deleted all the `.pyc` files, including all the `__pycache__` directories?

Comment: @LexScarisbrick where do i find all the .pyc files, including all the __pycache__ directories?

Comment: There's a solution in the duplicate I referenced above :)